# How to build puzzle captcha in angular

Tags: angular

am using the library https://github.com/KelvinDong/ng-spc
but it's not completed it always shows an error. Help me to build a puzzle captcha

[image]

Thanks in advance

Comment: Could you specify the error?

Comment: There can be lots of error here. No one can help with image. Code is needed , error is needed

Comment: added above, please check the image

Comment: am using the same library https://github.com/KelvinDong/ng-spc